# React Native, Firebase, assigning positions to elements entered in TextInput in an array

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to programming, and I have such a problem. When entering a set of digits into TextInput for example: "5, 4 ,5, 3, 5" and so on. and sending these numbers to an array located in the Firestore turns out this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BelFu.png)

And it should turn out something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82SEA.png)

What is the problem? Please help me! Here is my code:

```
const [numberInput, setNumberInput] = useState()

// Sending a value.
const EditSubject = () => {
    const addSub = doc(db, 'users', userUID, 'evaluations', 'SecondCours', 'FirstSemestr', 'FirstSemestr');
    if (textInput != undefined) {
    updateDoc(addSub, {Mathematics: [numberInput]});
    setModalWindow(false)
    } else {
    setModalWindow(false)
    }
   }

// Getting the value.
<TextInput style={[{backgroundColor: theme.colors.addSubjectText, color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.TInput]} keyboardType = 'numeric' onChangeText={num => setNumberInput(num)}/>
```

I will be very grateful if you help!

Answer (score 1):

The input code you have shown above is fine. You are rendering the entire numberInput array into a single element of your UI. Try using a [map](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) to iterate over the elements of the array and generate a row for each. Your result should look very similar to the linked example, you will just need to add an element for the numbered box.

**Edit:**

In your section `Displaying a table with subjects, grades, and the result of grades.` you need to make use of the map function. Try this instead:

```
rows = {
    item.map((key, lineItem) => {
        <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1, width: 175,}, styles.tableSubject]}>{lineItem.subject}</Text>
        <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1, flex: 1}, styles.tableMarks]}>{lineItem.marks}</Text>
        <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1, width: 60, backgroundColor: theme.colors.background}, styles.tableItog]}>{lineItem.itog}</Text>
        <View style={[{width: 98, flexDirection: 'row'}]}>
    }
}
```

Then, in your main body, you can replace the 4 `<Text>` lines with a single div containing the rows component. Hopefully this solves your issues.

Comment: And what it should look like in my code. I just tried using the map in this form: NumberInput.map(), but I get the error: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'NumberInput.map')"

Comment: Can you please update your question with your code that is rendering the page? This will help a lot in providing an answer.

Comment: I tried using the map both inside the code for sending values to the firestore and in the output to the console.       const EditSubject = () => {
    const addSub = doc(db, 'users', userUID, 'evaluations', 'SecondCours', 'FirstSemestr', 'FirstSemestr');
    if (textInput != undefined) {
    updateDoc(addSub, {[itemIndex.key]: [textInput.map((key, item) => {return (key, item)})]});
    setModalWindow(false)
    } else {
    setModalWindow(false)
    }
   }

  console.log(textInput.map((key, item) => {return (key, item)}))

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: If you're just trying to gain an understanding of how map() works, try changing your final line to `textInput.map((key, item) => {console.log("key " + key.toString() + ", item: " + item.toString())})`

Comment: If you execute your code and enter numbers separated by commas and spaces in TextInput, this is output to the console - " key 1,,, item: 1
key 2, , item: 2
key 3,4, item: 3
key 4,,, item: 4
key 5, , item: 5
key 6,5, item: 6
key 7,,, item: 7
key 8, , item: 8
key 9,5, item: 9
key 10,,, item: 10
key 11, , item: 11
key 12,3, item: 12
key 13,,, item: 13
key 14, , item: 14
key 15,5, item: 15"

Comment: And if you use it to send it to firestore, an error comes out: "FirebaseError error: The updateDoc() function is called with invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported (found in the document users/ED9jQcfOEBZM2nYbFrIJfLACIs12/estimates/secondcours/firstsemestr/FirstSemestr)"

Comment: The code was like this: const EditSubject = () => {
const addSub = doc(db, 'users', userUID, 'grades', 'Second courses', 'FirstSemestr', 'FirstSemestr');
 if (TextInput != undefined) {
updateDoc(addsub, {Mathematics: [element]});
setModalWindow(false)
} else {
setModalWindow(false)
}
}
 const element = Object.entries(TextInput).map((key, element) => {return key})

Comment: As I said above, I believe that your issue has more to do with how you are displaying the input, rather than how you are receiving it. Can you please update your question with your code used to print/display the values?

Comment: Judging by the "Edit" tab: I have to change the table display code, and in Firestore, instead of an array, use rows with scores, for example: Matematics: "5, 4, 5, 3, 5", instead of Matematics: [5, 4, 5, 3, 5]. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes that sounds correct, generate a row for the table for each values of Mathematics

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is part of my code. He is responsible for displaying the table of subjects, grades and totals on the screen. And editing the same ratings. But I have this error that I mentioned above.

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView, FlatList, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, Modal, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { gStyle } from '../../../Styles/gStyle';
import { useTheme } from 'styled-components';
import { db } from '../../../../firebase';
import {doc, updateDoc, onSnapshot, deleteField, query, collection, deleteDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function FirstSemestr() {
  const [modalWindow, setModalWindow] = useState(false)
  const [mwState, setMwState] = useState();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [userUID, setUserUID] = useState()
  const auth = getAuth();
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState([])
  const [evaluations, setEvaluations] = useState([])
  const [itemIndex, setItemIndex] = useState()

  //Get data from Firebase.
  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    setUserUID(user.uid)
    const UserUID = user.uid;
    const evaluation = onSnapshot(doc(db, 'users',  UserUID, 'evaluations', 'SecondCours', 'FirstSemestr', 'FirstSemestr'), (doc) => {
      const data = doc.data();
      setEvaluations(Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {return {'key': key, 'subject': ' '+key, 'marks': ' '+value.join(', ')+' ', 'itog': value.reduce((r,i) => r + i/value.length, 0.0).toFixed(1)}}))
    })
      return { evaluation }
  })
  }, [])

   //Edit Subject
   const EditSubject = () => {
    const addSub = doc(db, 'users', userUID, 'evaluations', 'SecondCours', 'FirstSemestr', 'FirstSemestr');
    if (textInput != undefined) {
    updateDoc(addSub, {[itemIndex.key]: [item]});
    setModalWindow(false)
    } else {
    setModalWindow(false)
    }
   }

  const item = Object.entries(textInput).map((key, item) => {return key});
  console.log(item);
   
   //Open my ModalWindow
   const editSubject = (item) => {
    setTextInput([])
    setMwState()
    setMwState('editSub')
    setItemIndex()
    setItemIndex(item)
    setModalWindow(true)
   }

   const cancellation = () => {
    setMwState()
    setTextInput()
    setModalWindow(false)
   }

  return (
    <View style={[{backgroundColor: theme.colors.boxBackground, alignItems: 'center'}]}>
      <ScrollView
        style={{width: '100%'}}
        horizontal={true} 
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator ={false}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>

      <Modal statusBarTranslucent transparent={true} animationType='fade' visible={modalWindow}>
        <View style={[{backgroundColor: theme.colors.addSubject}, styles.modalWindow]}>
        {mwState == 'eddSub' ? 
        <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.modalHeaderText]}>Добавление предмета</Text>:
        mwState == 'delSub' ? 
        <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.modalHeaderText]}>Удаление предмета</Text>: 
        mwState == 'editSub' ? 
        <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.modalHeaderText]}>Изменение предмета</Text>:
        <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.modalHeaderText]}></Text>
        }
        {mwState == 'eddSub' ? 
        <TextInput style={[{backgroundColor: theme.colors.addSubjectText, color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.TInput]} maxLength={15} onChangeText={text => setTextInput(text)}/>:
        mwState == 'delSub' ? 
        <Text style={[{color: '#ad1a00'}, styles.modalHeaderText]}>Вы дейстительно хотите удалить предмет {itemIndex.key}?</Text>: 
        mwState == 'editSub' ? 
        <View>  
        <ScrollView
        style={{width: '100%'}}
        horizontal={true} 
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator ={false}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: 5, marginTop: 5, marginBottom: 5}}>
        <Text style={[{color: '#fff', borderWidth: 1}, styles.modalHeaderText]}>{itemIndex.key}</Text>
        <Text selectable={true} style={[{color: '#fff', borderWidth: 1}, styles.modalHeaderText]}>{itemIndex.marks}</Text>
        </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <View>
        <Text style={[{color: '#fff', marginBottom: 5}, styles.modalHeaderText]}>Для изменения введите все оценки {"\n"} (можно скопировать сверху)</Text>

        //Edit my Marks
        <TextInput style={[{backgroundColor: theme.colors.addSubjectText, color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.TInput]} keyboardType = 'numeric' onChangeText={text => setTextInput(text)}/>
        </View>
        </View>:
        <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.modalHeaderText]}></Text>
        }
        {mwState == 'eddSub' ? 
        <View style={styles.buttonStyles}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={otmena}
          style={[{backgroundColor: '#ad3f00'}, styles.button]}
          >
           <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.buttonText]}>Отмена</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={AddSubject}
          style={[{backgroundColor: '#00ad5c'}, styles.button]}
          >
           <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.buttonText]}>Добавить</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>:
        mwState == 'delSub' ? 
        <View style={styles.buttonStyles}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={otmena}
          style={[{backgroundColor: '#00ad5c'}, styles.button]}
          >
           <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.buttonText]}>Отмена</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={DelSubject}
          disabled={butDisTimer == 0 ? false : true}
          style={[{backgroundColor: butDisTimer == 0 ? '#ad3f00' : '#642500', }, styles.button]}
          >
           <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.buttonText]}>{butDisTimer == 0 ? 'Удалить' : butDisTimer}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>: 
        mwState == 'editSub' ? 
        <View style={styles.buttonStyles}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={otmena}
          style={[{backgroundColor: '#ad3f00'}, styles.button]}
          >
           <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.buttonText]}>Отмена</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={EditSubject}
          style={[{backgroundColor: '#00ad5c'}, styles.button]}
          >
           <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.buttonText]}>Изменить</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>:
        <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.modalHeaderText]}></Text>
        }
        </View>
      </Modal>

      //Displaying a table with subjects, grades, and the result of grades.
      <View style={{marginBottom: 10, width: '100%'}}>
      <View style={[styles.table]}>
        <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.tableHeaderSubject]}>Предмет</Text>
        <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.tableHeaderMarks]}>Оценки</Text>
        <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1, backgroundColor: theme.colors.background}, styles.tableHeaderItog]}>Итог</Text>
        <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1}, styles.tableHeaderEdit]}>Изменить</Text>
        
      </View>
      <View style={[styles.table]}>
      <FlatList 
      horizontal={false}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator = {false}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = {false}
      data={evaluations.sort((a, b) => a.key.localeCompare(b.key))} 
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <View style={[styles.table]}>
        <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1, width: 175,}, styles.tableSubject]}>{item.subject}</Text>
        <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1, flex: 1}, styles.tableMarks]}>{item.marks}</Text>
        <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1, width: 60, backgroundColor: theme.colors.background}, styles.tableItog]}>{item.itog}</Text>
        <View style={[{width: 98, flexDirection: 'row'}]}>
        <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => editSubject(item)}
        style={[{}, styles.editButton]}
        >
          <AntDesign name="edit" size={26} color={'#008648'} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => delSubject(item)}
        style={[{}, styles.editButton]}
        >
          <AntDesign name="delete" size={26} color={'#ad3f00'} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
      )}/>
      </View>
      </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => eddSubject()}
        style={gStyle.CouEvalTableNewEval}
        >
          <Text style={[{color: theme.colors.text1}, gStyle.CouEvalTableNewEvalText]}>Добавить предмет</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```